# Pandas: how to groupby with count with multiple levels on rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
|----|----|
| A  | B  |
| a1 | b1 |
| a2 | b1 |
| a1 | b2 |
| a2 | b3 |
```

I want to count by **B** per **A** and get the following result:

```
|----|----|-------|
| A  | B  | Count |
| a1 | b1 |  1    |
|    | b2 |  1    |
|    | b3 |  NaN  |
| a2 | b1 |  1    |
|    | b2 |  NaN  |
|    | b3 |  1    |
```

I usually do this with `df.groupby([B])[A].count()` but in this case with kinda pivot table it's confusing for me

Thanks in advance.

UPDT:

`df.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 20422 entries, 180 to 96430
Data columns (total 2 columns):
B    20422 non-null object
A             20422 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 478.6+ KB
```

I'm getting with `df.groupby([B])[A].value_counts().unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name="Count")`:

```
|--|----|----|-------|
|  | A  | B  | Count |
|0 | a1 | b1 |  1    |
|1 | a1 | b2 |  1    |
|2 | a1 | b3 |  NaN  |
|3 | a2 | b1 |  1    |
|4 | a2 | b2 |  NaN  |
|5 | a2 | b3 |  1    |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) One way would be grouping on `"A"` and computing the distinct counts of elements under `"B"` using [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Then a fusion of `unstack` and `stack` with `dropna=False` to get the desired `DF`:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts().unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name="Count")
```

2) [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) also provides a good alternative if we replace the zero count elements with `np.NaN` after stacking:

```
pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B']).stack().replace({0:np.nan}).reset_index(name="Count")
```

Both approaches yield:

[image]

---

***edit1:***

To have the grouped key, `"A"` be displayed in a certain format (i.e keep the first occurence while replacing the rest with an empty string)

```
df_g = pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B']).stack().replace({0:np.nan}).reset_index(name="Count")
df_g.loc[df_g.duplicated('A'), "A"] = ""
```

[image]

***edit2:***

If you want `"A"` as a single wholesome cell being part of a multi-indexed `DF`:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts().unstack().stack(dropna=False
                    ).reset_index(name="Count").set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this didn't help. It does count on new Count column but does not group by per A. Probably first "count" column is the reason, please review my updates. Also thanks for @Tim's answer, but same issue

Comment: Alright, it the issue is with the displaying of cells, then take a look at the edit.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But probably not in right way, because it does not combine cells in one cell, but set duplicates as empty string. So rows number might be the issue. I appreciate your effort, I will probably go with your groupping with some dirty edition :)

`df_g = df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts().unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name="Count")`
`df_g.groupby([A, B])['Count'].sum().to_frame()`

Comment: edit2 is the right and nice solution. bellissimo! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could groupby both columns and access the size of each group:

```
 df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size()
```

returns:

```
A   B 
a1  b1    1
    b2    1
a2  b1    1
    b3    1
dtype: int64
```

It won't give you `NaN`'s for non existing combinations though.

Comment: avoid using `apply` especially when `groupby` has custom made functions for the exact same purpose. Look for `groupby.size` method.