# Pandas: how to operate with each pivottable value?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998660/pandas-how-to-groupby-with-count-with-multiple-levels-on-rows). Let's say I have code that does this table I want

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts().unstack().stack(dropna=False
                ).reset_index(name="Count").set_index(['A', 'B'])

|----|----|-------|
| A  | B  | Count |
| a1 | b1 |  1    |
|    | b2 |  1    |
|    | b3 |  NaN  |
| a2 | b1 |  1    |
|    | b2 |  NaN  |
|    | b3 |  1    |
```

The problem is that there is the case where **B** column might have multivariate values, e.g. many unique values. So the groupping **A** column values are a bit far away :) Eventually, this all should be stored in some Excel format file `df.to_excel()`. The solution was proposed to generate such as Excel files per **A** values. E.g. instead of *groupped.xlsx*  where you have all this pivot table in once, to have *A_a1.xlsx, A_a2.xlsx* files.

Question: how do you do it?

I have some options in mind like to get the list of unique **A** values and just do something like `df_loc = df.loc[df['A'] == 'a1']`, but maybe there is more cool way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're looking for an individual excel file for each A value? If so, the following should work:

`for i in df.a.unique():
  df[df['a'] == i].to_excel(path+_i)`

You can tweak the path for your needs but this is a pretty easy way to do what you're looking for.