# groupby sub ranges of ranges - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a quite complex groupby operation with pandas.
Consider two data frames:

```
df1:
begin, end, y
0, 3, string10
3, 7, string11


df2:
begin, end, x
0, 2, string1
1, 2, string2
3, 4, string3
4, 6, string4
```

This two DF represents time slots with some properties. DF1 contains large time slots and its borders will always be bigger than DF2.
Also each begin end in DF2 will always be contained or equal to one of the time slots in DF1.

What I need to do is to group DF2 according to DF1 slots keeping their properties:

```
result:
index, slot, begin_df2, end_df2, x, y
0, (0,3), 0, 2, string1, string10
 , (0,3), 1, 2, string2, string10
1, (3,6), 3, 4, string3, string11
 , (3,6), 4, 6, string4, string11
```

I can't find a reasonable flow at pandas API for this I tried to check:
[Pandas Groupby Range of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values)

But it is more for grouping single values in a range.

Comment: Try multiple levels grouping - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998660/pandas-how-to-groupby-with-count-with-multiple-levels-on-rows

Answer (score 0):

If your interval do not have intersection with each other in df1

```
df1['key']=df1.iloc[:,:1].mean(1)
df2['key']=df2.iloc[:,:1].mean(1)
df=pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,on='key')
df
Out[401]: 
   begin_x   end_x         x  key  begin_y   end_y          y
0        0       2   string1  0.0        0       3   string10
1        1       2   string2  1.0        0       3   string10
2        3       4   string3  3.0        3       7   string11
3        4       6   string4  4.0        3       7   string11
```

Comment: It's a bit problematic. There is no possibility for overlaping, but there is a case where there is no element in df2 which contained in element from df1. I still need it to be in the table with NaN.

Comment: @user3741859 you can merge df back with df2:-)